# Hermitian matrices and their eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples

Let $C=A+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are two hermitian matrices can I prove that $\lambda_{i,C}=\lambda_{i,A}+\lambda_{i,B}$ iff $x_{i,A}=x_{i,B}$? Where $x_i$ is the eigenvector related to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

Comment: this question is not well-posed. In fact in general, if you have n eigenvalue for A and m for B, then you have many possibility for the sum of two of them, so what exactly your hypothesis "$\lambda_{i,C}=\lambda_{i,A}+\lambda_{i,B}$" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Clearly the first equality always holds, however $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\  1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $B$, but not of $A$.

Comment: the second also holds in your example as any non-null vector is eigenvector of A,B,C

Comment: @user126154 Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I edited my answer.

Comment: What do you think about http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698668/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-two-particular-matrices?